# Cannot connect to docker mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, sails.js, sails-mongo, fig

I am setting up a project using [sane](http://sanestack.com/) with docker.  After creating the project to use mongodb and createing a resource I tried running it, but got an error reporting that the server container could not connect to mongo.  I then tried just running `fig up` to see if it was a fig problem and got the same error.  Here is my `fig.yml` (irrelevant comments removed):

```
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
server:
  image: artificial/docker-sails:stable-pm2
  command: sails lift
  volumes:
    - server/:/server
  ports:
    - "1337:1337"
  links:
    - db
```

The full error report on `fig up` is as follows (the error report on `sane up` is the same, although the output from `db_1` is more terse and there are also lines of output for the client):

```
Recreating hydro_db_1...
Recreating hydro_server_1...
Attaching to hydro_db_1, hydro_server_1
db_1     | mongod --help for help and startup options
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.092+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=b7a85ddb94e2
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.093+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.094+0000 [initandlisten] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.094+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.094+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.094+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.099+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.099+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
db_1     | 2015-02-17T13:32:00.274+0000 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
server_1 | 
server_1 | info: Starting app...
server_1 | 
server_1 | error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
server_1 | error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
server_1 |  Error details:
server_1 | [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
server_1 |     at _createError (/server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:98:23)
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:101:13
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/connection.js:25:20
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:406:11
server_1 |     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13) { [Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
server_1 |  Error details:
server_1 | [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]]
server_1 |   originalError: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]] }
server_1 | error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
server_1 |  Error details:
server_1 | [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
server_1 |     at _createError (/server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:98:23)
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:101:13
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/connection.js:25:20
server_1 |     at /server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:406:11
server_1 |     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13) { [Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
server_1 |  Error details:
server_1 | [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]]
server_1 |   originalError: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]] }
hydro_server_1 exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping hydro_db_1...
```

I'm not sure if this is a docker problem, a fig problem, a sane problem, or a sails problem.  I also cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like `localhost` needs to be replaced with the mongo container IP, which you should be able to get from an environment variable.

Comment: Of course! Now I feel like an idiot... Actually in my case is it as simple as setting the host to `db`.  Thanks for pointing that out, if you post it as answer I'll accept it

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sure it was a simple as it looked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `localhost` with the mongo container IP, which you should be able to get from an environment variable that Docker will populate for you.

Docker will also set up an entry for `db` in `/etc/hosts` that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running MongoDB through Docker, and I got it to work with this:

```
$ export dockerip="$(docker-machine ls | awk '{print $5}' | sed -n '2p' | sed 's/tcp:\/\///' | sed 's/\:2376//')"
$ mongo --host "$dockerip" --port 27017
```

Comment: A bit of explanation on what those lines do would be nice.